# Insert filename in the beginning of each line of output txt file using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to insert filename in the beginning of each line of my log file, but I have a `;` in the beginning of some lines and I want to keep it.

I have succeeded in the insertion of the filename but the semicolons `;` have disappeared.

For example, I have this in the beginning:

> ```
> 1254778;FGT_1;1447;ggft....
> ;YH_4;14788;hhth;warning....
> 774895;HG_5;4778.....
> ;TR_8;7885;.....
> ```

And after using my code I have this:

> ```
> FILENAME 1254778;FGT_1;1447;ggft....
> FILENAME YH_4;14788;hhth;warning....
> FILENAME 774895;HG_5;4778.....
> FILENAME TR_8;7885;.....
> ```

And this is my code:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%a in (file1.log) do (
echo FILENAME %%a >>FILE1_.txt
)
```

For me I'm trying to have this:

> ```
> FILENAME 1254778;FGT_1;1447;ggft....
> FILENAME ;YH_4;14788;hhth;warning....
> FILENAME 774895;HG_5;4778.....
> FILENAME ;TR_8;7885;.....
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the option string of [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) from `"tokens=* delims=;"` to `delims^=^ eol^=` (yes, without quotes) in order to disable both delimiters and end-of-line characters:

```cmd
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("file1.log") do (
    echo FILENAME %%a>>"FILE1_.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a go at this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "file1.log" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "FILE1_.txt"') do (
        set "str=%%a"
        call set "str=%%str:*]=%%"
        echo FILENAME !str!>> FILE1_.txt
)
```

We really just add line numbers so we can replicate the lines exactly and then simply get rid of the line numbers before we print to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it if you wanted to push ahead into PowerShell.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\file1.log' | "^
        "ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f @('FILENAME', $_) } | "^
        "Out-File -FilePath '.\FILE1.txt' -Encoding ascii"
TYPE .\FILE1.txt
```